# number format exception

Tags: java

hi my code is giving the error while saving the data. error is coming in DATE i have taken datatype of this DATE as date/ time in ms access DB.i have also given my code,error below

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input     string: "4.5.5255"

        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:456)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:497)
        at sanskarwani.saveREGISTRATION1(sanskarwani.java:3667)
        at sanskarwani.access$800(sanskarwani.java:31)
        at sanskarwani$9.actionPerformed(sanskarwani.java:1224)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
        at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:272)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6038)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3260)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5803)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2058)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4410)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2116)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4322)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3986)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3916)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2102)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2429)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:273)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:183)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:173)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:168)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:160)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:121)
```

my code is:

```
    int len,len1,len2;

    int regno= Integer.parseInt(cbregn.getSelectedItem().toString());
    if(cbregn.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("")){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," SELECT THE REGISTRATION NO ");
    return;
    }


      int dt=Integer.parseInt(tdate.getText());
      if(tdate.getText().equals(""))
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," ENTER THE DATE ");
//         String date=tdate.getText();
//         if(date.equals(""))
//         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," ENTER THE DATE ");


    String nm= cbnm.getSelectedItem().toString();
    if(nm.equals("")){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," ENTER THE NAME ");
    return;
    }


    String place=tfplace.getText();
    if(place.equals("")){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," ENTER THE NATIVE PLACE ");
    return;
    }



    String kul=tfkul.getText();
    if(kul.equals("")){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," ENTER THE NAME OF KUL ");
    return;
    }

    String gotra=tfgotra.getText();
    if(gotra.equals("")){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," ENTER THE GOTRA NAME ");
    return;
    }

    String kswami=tfswami.getText();
    if(kswami.equals("")){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," ENTER THE KULSWAMI NAME ");
    return;
    }

    String raddr=taraddr.getText();
    if(raddr.equals("")){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," ENTER THE RESIDENSIAL ADDRESS ");
    return;
    }

    int pincode=Integer.parseInt(tfpcd.getText());
    len1 = tfpcd.getText().length();
    if(len1!=7) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Enter The 7 Digit Pin Code","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    return;
    }

    int stdcd=Integer.parseInt(tfstdcode.getText());
    if(tfstdcode.getText().equals("")){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," ENTER THE STD CODE ");
    return;
    }


    int tele=Integer.parseInt(tftele.getText());
    len2 = tftele.getText().length();
    if(len2!=7){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Enter The 7 Digit Telephone No","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    return;
    }


    int mno=(int) Long.parseLong(tfmno.getText());
    len = tfmno.getText().length();
    if(len!=10) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Enter The 10 Digit Mobile No","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    return;
    }


    String email=tfemail.getText();
    if(email.equals(""))
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," ENTER THE EMAIL");

    if(email.equals("")) {
        tfemail.setText("-");

    } else // check if it is a valid email-id
    {
    int ind = email.indexOf("@");
        if (ind != -1) { } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Email Id","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            tfemail.setText("");
            tfemail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
    }
    String website=tfweb.getText();
    if(website.equals(""))
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," ENTER THE WEBSITE ");

    if(website.equals("")) {
        tfweb.setText("-");
    }
    else // check if it is a valid email-id
    {
    int ind = website.indexOf("www");
    if (ind != -1) { } else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Website","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    tfweb.setText("");
    tfweb.requestFocus();
    return;
   }
}

    String education=tfedu.getText();
    if(education.equals("")){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," ENTER THE EDUCATION DETAILS");
    return;
   }

    String branch=tfbrch.getText();
    if(branch.equals("")){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," ENTER THE BRANCH NAME ");
    return;
   }


  int bdt=Integer.parseInt(tfbdt.getText());
  if(tfbdt.getText().equals(""))
//      String brthdt=tfbdt.getText();
//      if(brthdt.equals(""))
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," ENTER THE BIRTH DATE");



    String bloodgrp=(String)cbbldgrp.getSelectedItem();
    if(bloodgrp.equals("")){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," SELECT THE BLOODGROUP");
    return;
   }

    try
    {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:wanisamajDB");
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
        String qry= "INSERT INTO Registration1(RegistrationNo,SeniorPerson,NativePlace,Kul,Gotra,KulSwami,ResidensialAddress,PinCode,STDcode,TelephoneNo,MobileNo,Email,Website,Education,Branch,BloodGroup,Date,BirthDate) VALUES('"+regno+"','"+nm+"','"+place+"','"+kul+"','"+gotra+"','"+kswami+"','"+raddr+"','"+pincode+"','"+stdcd+"','"+tele+"','"+mno+"','"+email+"','"+website+"','"+education+"','"+branch+"','"+bloodgrp+"','"+dt+"','"+bdt+"')";
       //            System.out.println("qry");
       // String qry= "INSERT INTO Registration1(RegistrationNo,SeniorPerson,NativePlace,Kul,Gotra,KulSwami,ResidensialAddress,PinCode,STDcode,TelephoneNo,MobileNo,Email,Website,Education,Branch,BloodGroup,Date,BirthDate) VALUES('"+regno+"','"+nm+"','"+place+"','"+kul+"','"+gotra+"','"+kswami+"','"+raddr+"','"+pincode+"','"+stdcd+"','"+tele+"','"+mno+"','"+email+"','"+website+"','"+education+"','"+branch+"','"+bloodgrp+"','"+dt+"','"+bdt+"')";
        stmt.executeUpdate(qry);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"RECORD IS SAVED SUCCESSFULLY ");
        con.close();

    }
    catch(SQLException eM) {
        System.out.println(" "+eM);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"RECORD IS NOT SAVED");
    } 
    catch(Exception et)
    {
        System.out.println("error:"+et.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: do you think 4.5.5255 is an integer ?

Comment: Change your title - `NumberFormatException` is not a `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 2):

you are trying to format a decimal in string format containing floating point to integer.

int types should not have floating points.

you can convert this string to integer:

```
455255
```

but this is not a correct integer:

```
4.5.5255
```

try this :

```
string number = "4.5.5255";
number = number.replace(".", "");
Integer.parseInt(number );
```

Answer (score 2):

First line in your execption:

> Exception 
>   in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For
>   input string: "4.5.5255"

It means you are trying to parse 4.5.5255 which is not a number.

It's hard to tell in which line in your code you get this exception.[may be at `sanskarwani.java:3667`]. I mean in the code you have posted how can we find line number 3667.  Try to debug your code and post the code where the error occurred separately.