# Getting NumberFormatException while Converting character String to Integer

Tags: java, numberformatexception

Getting `NumberFormatException` while Converting String to Integer and trying to print it.

My code:

```
BufferedReader bur=new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));   
String s=bur.readLine();        

int a=Integer.parseInt(s);
System.out.println(a);
```

input-rakib

Comment: Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Have you consulted your [Rubber Duck](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Comment: What's your input from `bur`? Could you print `s` and share it with us?

Comment: That means that `s` is a set of characters like this : "characters"

Comment: I suppose you use Java so it would be a good idea to use this Tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [number format exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604532/number-format-exception)

Comment: That code works fine for me. What are you inputting?

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex That code works fine for specific input string , try to input string "FOOBAR" and it will result NumberFormatException

Comment: That's why I asked what was inputted.

Comment: i am sorry. i am a noob and new in StackOverflow .@Sascha

Comment: i was inputting character string like "rakib" .  i wanted to convert character string into binary

Comment: @EmranulHaqueRakib _character string into binary_. What is that supposed to mean? The integer value of a character as binary digit? Then you should have a look at `Character.digit()` and `Integer.toBinaryString()`

Comment: thanks @ Würgspaß  ,i didn't ask my question properly.

Comment: @EmranulHaqueRakib ok, then I think you should edit your question, so that others get the right idea and do not have to read all these comments

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NumberFormatException and how can I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849984/what-is-a-numberformatexception-and-how-can-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print out the numerical vaĺue of each character of a text input to binary digit, replace your last two lines with this:

```
for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
    int charValueAsInt = (int)s.charAt(i);
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(charValueAsInt)); 
}
```

Retrieve the `char` value of each character, convert it to `int` (widening conversion) and then convert to binary digit.

Answer (score 0):

You can get chars from String, than can obtain integer value for each char as below

```
BufferedReader bur=new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));   
String str = bur.readLine();   
char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
for(char c: chars){
    System.out.println((int)c);
}
```